# The mean of iterations for choosing a unique set

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, mean-value-theorem

We need to choose a set of unique numbers  (with replacement) out of a group of n unique numbers. The set we choose should end up being in the size of exactly 10% of the group(n/10). What would be the mean of the amount of iterations we have to preform in order to get to this request? I'm a new statistic student so I have no clue how to get to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.